# How do you create a list of objects to pass to a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I am trying to find out how to create a list of objects like below and pass it to a widget so I can use it like _imageList[0].label, _imageList[0].path and etc...

```
List<Object> _imageList = List(); <-

_imageList.add({
    'label': 'Image1',
    'path': 'lib/assets/image/image1.png',
    'active': '0xFFFFFFFF',
    'inactive': '0x32FFFFFF'
  });

_imageList.add({
    'label': 'Image2',
    'path': 'lib/assets/image/image2.png',
    'active': '0xFFFFFFFF',
    'inactive': '0x32FFFFFF'
  });
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a class.

```
class AppImage{
  String? image;
  String? path;
  String? active;
  String? inactive;

// added '?'
  
  AppImage({this.image, this.path, this.active, this.inactive});
  // can also add 'required' keyword
}
```

Now you can use it as a list of Objects;

```
List<AppImage> images = [
    AppImage(image: "imageUrl", path: "path", active: "active", inactive: "inactive"),
    
     AppImage(image: "imageUrl2", path: "path2", active: "active2", inactive: "inactive2"),
  ];
```

And you can use the values accordingly:

```
AppImage appImage = images[0];
  print(appImage.path);
```

To learn more, check out [this article](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@tensor/object-oriented-programming-and-classes-in-the-dart-programming-language-dart-tutorial-part-2).